# Python - browser pages managment

Tags: python, google-chrome, automation

I am using Google Chrome and I need to **find** a way of finding **on existing window and existing page** way of interaction with it ( clicking on something and all that stuff ). **Important: without creating a new browser or new page**. running code => opening that page and the code after X seconds => interact with page

Comment: Have you considered [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)?

Comment: yes, but it creates new browser and new page

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Do you want to open a browser yourself, do X, then ask the program to do Y in the browser you opened?

Comment: absolutely right

Comment: Couldn't you open a new browser with Selenium, use that browser manually to do X, and then run the program to perform Y? I believe it will work in the same browser.

Comment: Sad, but I am opening WhatsApp Web and every time I create new browser I need to verify through phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244744/discussion-between-econbernardo-and-lev-shapiro).